# Как создать текстовый файл на стороне клиента но не отдавая файл клиенту

Tags: javascript, php, txt

Мне нужно собрать данние с форм и записать их в текстовий файл, с помочью js. Но насколько я знаю js не умеет так работать, надо подключить тут php и тут проблема так как в нем я полный 0. Сервера нету, припустим есть вот такая разметка.

```
    <input type="text" id="fileName">

    <select id="cities">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

   <button class="btn-submit">Submit</button>
```

При клике на кнопку нужно собрать данние и записать в txt файл, с названием например properties.properties.
Каждый раз при клике на кнопку нужно создавать новый файл с новыми данними, + надо еще возможность задавать путь создания файла относительно файла со скриптом. Как ето возможно реальзировать без сервера ?

Comment: Записать в файл на сервере? Тогда без PHP (или чего-нибудь другого серверного) не обойтись.

Comment: Не на сервер, а получаеться допустым около index.html. Я знаю что без сервеного языка не обойтись, по етому и прошу о помощи )

Comment: Так ты клиенту отдаешь файл. Тебе на сервере нужно сохранить или у клиента ? Если у клиента, то он по любому будет выбирать путь сохранения, так работает браузер IE из соображений безопасности. Хром ,например, сразу загружает в папку загрузок. В общем это настройки конкретного браузера и со стороны сервера на них не повлиять.

Comment: index.php у тебя на сервере. поэтому "около index.html" - это **тоже** на сервере. И в любом случае создать на клиенте ничего нельзя. Можно только на сервере.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php" >
<input type="text" name="name" id="fileName">
<select name="name1" id="cities">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<button class="btn-submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php
$arrs[]=$_POST['name'];
$arrs[]=$_POST['name1];

$file1='noname.txt';

foreach ($arrs as $key => $str) {
  
file_put_contents($file1, $str."\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

}
?>
```